# How to avoid to have is bundle app quarantine flagged by MacOS on Mac M1?

Tags: macos, apple-m1, macos-monterey

everytime I share a bundle app to a friend, he get his .app quarantine-flagged and he need to use xattr -c "Bundle.app". How to avoid that ?

Answer (score 0):

Join the Apple developer Program (https://developer.apple.com/programs/) and then you can code sign and have Apple notarize your applications.

See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much, I already seen the developper program but since it's not clear that it solve the problem and it's not very easy to join I've abandonned the idea. And sorry for the dupplicated question but every time I post a question I'm vote down and nobody anwser so I reposted it with different words. I've just seen it's 99€  too bad...

Comment: It most definitely does solve the problem which you presented. That is the whole point of your signing and Apple notarizing applications!